# How to retreive Endpoint Production / Sandbox on WSO2

Tags: wso2, endpoint, wso2-esb

I have an API which integrated with WSO2_APIM version 2.1.0

And what i want achieve, How i can retrieve current Endpoint(Defined on API Publisher - Implement Tab) used which using environment(Production / Sandbox) on my .xml File(Which declared on In Sequence).
The purpose for Sequence(.xml File) can filter environment used between Production / Sandbox, which will be used for Set Address Endpoint with Call Mediator.

Hope Someone can give any ideas. Thanks for any comments & responses.

Comment: Inside the sequence, do you want to retrieve whether current request is for Production or Sandbox ? Else do you also want the endpoint address values as well?

Comment: Hi Lakmali Thx for ur responses, i want to retreive current request used. For eg: I'm using Production Environment, and my Friends using Sandbox Environment. Inside the Sequence it can check automatically Endpoints Environment from user.
Can I do that? or can i get both of Production & Sandbox Endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the environment that current request being used through 'AM_KEY_TYPE' property. You can use the filter mediator inside your sequence to check the value of that property. If it is 'PRODUCTION' then, the current environment is prod and else it is sandbox.

```
<filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
        <then>
            <!--Your logic for prod case-->
        </then>
        <else>
             <!--Your logic for sandbox case-->
        </else>
</filter>
```

Comment: Hi Lakmali Thx for ur responses, Sorry but that's not what i mean, if that's code only filter Environment current used right?
But what i need is how to retreive the end points defined on WSO2APIM Publisher, which is environment production / sandbox?